# HTML and WMP plugin - Play DVD files

Tags: html, embed, windows-media-player

I need to play a `VIDEO_TS` folder (as in DVD format) in a webpage. I am trying to embed Windows Media Player plugin to play the contents of the folder. So far I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
....
<body>
....
<OBJECT id="mediaPlayer" width="500" height="500" CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" type="application/x-oleobject">
    <PARAM NAME="URL" VALUE="dvd://VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.IFO" />
    <PARAM NAME="SendPlayStateChangeEvents" VALUE="True"/>
    <PARAM NAME="AutoStart" VALUE="True"/>
    <PARAM NAME="uiMode" VALUE="full"/>
    <PARAM NAME="volume" VALUE="50" />
    <PARAM NAME="PlayCount" VALUE="9999"/>
    <PARAM NAME="enableContextMenu" VALUE="true"/>
</OBJECT>
....
</body>
</html>
```

The plugin shows up, but the video won't play. WMP reports that

> The file you are trying to play has an extension that does not match the format

or something similar. Then it just shows a black screen.

The `VIDEO_TS` folder is located next to the HTML page on my web server, and contains the standard `VTS[_xx[_y]].{IFO|BUP|VOB}` files, along with `VIDEO_TS.IFO`/`BUP`/`VOB`.

I have also tried setting the `URL` param to `./VIDEO_TS/` and `./VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.IFO`; neither works. However, if I use `./VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.IFO` and view the page from my local filesystem (ie, with `file:///`), it does work.

How can I get WMP (or any other media player HTML plugin) to play a DVD `VIDEO_TS` folder?

Comment: Could you convert the files to a browser standard format?

Comment: No, because I wish to preserve the menus and chapter structure.